# Paypal IPN not sending response (SANDBOX mode)

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

NO IPN response after successful recurring transaction in sandbox mode, is there some issue with paypal sandbox in last couple of days?

Comment: My sandbox IPN's have been working fine.  Are you sure you configured IPN in the sandbox seller account you're working with?  Have you checked your IPN History and your web server logs to confirm that you're not actually getting IPN hits but your script is failing?

Comment: IPN history is showing the details perfectly, I have correctly configured IPN in my merchant account. I will check my server logs.

If i send IPN response through IPN simulator, it works fine.

Comment: If your IPN History is showing that it was POSTed then it was POSTed.    If the IPN wasn't sent it wouldn't show up at all in the IPN history for the account.